# Word frequency counter for excel using Python

Tags: python

I have the following python code to count the number of occurrences in an excel file. This is written to work even if a cell contains a sentence. However, for some reasons it's not working and I get TypeError: argument of type 'Cell' is not iterable.

Can someone help.

```
import xlrd
import os
for filename in os.listdir("D:\MyData\MyPythonCodes\Excel reading\search using xlrd"):
if filename.find('xlsx') != -1:
    print(filename)        
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
    values = []
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            if " " in sheet.cell(row,col):
                values.append(str(sheet.cell(row,col).value.split(" ")))
            else:
                values.append(str(sheet.cell(row,col)))
print(values.count("abcd")) times")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need the following changes :

```
import xlrd
import os

for filename in os.listdir("D:\MyData\MyPythonCodes\Excel reading\search using xlrd"):
    if filename.find('xlsx') != -1:
        print(filename)        
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
        values = []
        for row in range(sheet.nrows):
            for col in range(sheet.ncols):
                value = str(sheet.cell(row,col).value)
                if " " in value:
                    for word in value.split(" "):
                        values.append(word)
                else:
                    values.append(value)

        print("%s times" % values.count("abcd"))
```

Comment: Great! The good news is, it's not giving me any error. However, no matter what I have in my sheet, the counter returns 0 value.

Comment: sorry i didn't look at the last line. `str(value.split(' '))` will give you something like `"['abcd', 'abcd']"` , you want to delete the space and join the values or get the separate values in your list ?

Comment: Well. I just need the number of times abcd has occurred in my list.

Comment: so you need to loop on `value.split(' ')` instead of append `"['abcd', 'abcd']"` in the list `values`.  print your list to see what's inside, you will understand what's wrong

Comment: I am new to Python. It would be great if you could elaborate on the code.

Comment: print(value) returns "['abcd', 'abcd']" since I am using append. But not sure how to loop on value.spli(' ')

Comment: `values.count("abcd")` can only count the items in your list that match 'abcd', it cannot find the word 'hidden' in a sublist or a subchain. check the edit

Comment: Appreciate your help PRMoureu. But I am still unable to do so. Can you post the correct version of code if possible? I know it's a little more to ask. :)

Comment: what do you get with `print(values)` or `values.count("abcd")` ?

Comment: print(value) >> ["['Ritesh', 'a']", "text:'abcd'"]  print(value.count("abcd")) >> 0

Comment: i don't know what's inside your excel file but it's weird you get these results with the code i edited above, except for the ':' which is not handled

Comment: my excel cell contains only two entries, A1: Ritesh a and A2: abcd. It's just for testing. All I want to do is count the number of occurrences of a specific word in an excel file.

Comment: Awesome!! Now I understood how to use loop in this case. Many thanks.